# How to pass function into non related component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component called MainMenu.js which is having a function called getMenuData() which is used to update values of the MainMenu component via it's service.

```
class MainMenu extends Component {

 getMenuData = (action) => {
...
 }
<ul className="treeview-menu">
              {item.categories.map(aItem => (
                <li
                  key={aItem.id}
                  className={` ${
                    searchParams.type === aItem.name ? "active" : ""
                  }`}
                >
              <Link
                 to={{
                      pathname: "/categories/" + item.id,
                      search: "?type=" + aItem.name,
                state: {
                   actionId: item.actionId,
                }
                }}>
           <i className="fa fa-circle-o" />
               {aItem.label}                        
               </Link>
              </li>
  ))}
  </ul>


export default MainMenu;
```

There is another component called **Home.js** which requires access to **getMenu()** function. Home component is not a child component of MainMenu. How can I get a reference for getMenuData to Home.js? Is there any way that I can access it via props?

Answer (score 1):

If the function doesn't use any state manipulation you can just take it out of the component and export it

Comment: This is actually a good point. Almost always isn't the case. But this could definitely works

Comment: welp, didn't see the function so :P

Comment: Yes you are right. It's hard to guess without looking at the implementation. I've forgot to upvote your answer

Comment: @voiys this function should be called inside the Home component to update some of the values in MainMenu.

Comment: then it depends on how the component uses those values. if your component just fetches data via the function then displays it you can take it out of the component, however if it's coupled with state you might want to life the state up and pass the function down to Home and MainMenu

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is called [Lift the State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) (but in your case, is not the state, is a function)

What you could do is

```
function WrapperComponent(){
    const getMenuData = (action) => {...}

    return (
        <>
            <MainMenu getMenuData={getMenuData} />
            <Home getMenuData={getMenuData} />
        </>
    )    
}
```

OR

If `getMenuData` is a function that only depends on it's arguments, you could just put it in another file and import it to both components.